# breaking datetime into constituent parts ASP.NET MVC form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, forms, modelbinders, html-helper

i have searched the web relentlessly for this and have not found anything - which is surprising because i would think it is such a common scenario!

Basically, on my model i have a `DateTime` field which i wish the user to populate through a form. I am using the Html helper to render all other parts of the form (along with validation)

So this question is in two parts...

#### Html Helper

Firstly, is there any way to use the Html helper to split the `DateTime` field to be rendered as the three constituent parts of a date: day, month, year (since i do not care about the time part). This could be rendered as text boxes, drop down lists or a combination of both.

#### Model Binding

And then when the form is posted, what is the best approach for binding back up to the model? I have seen [Scott Hanselmann's solution](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) to this, but it seems a little bloated for what i need - i was hoping for a slightly more elegant solution. Is it recommended to extend `DefaultModelBinder` and set that as default binder (since all dates would be handled in this way) or write a class that implements `IModelBionder` and set it as the default binder for the `DateTime` type?

Thanks for all the help in advance :-) i'm loving MVC but it's infuriating me that something so trivial is causing so much headaches!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think i've worked out a decent solution to this, so i will provide an answer for any who stumble across this in future!

With regards to the Html helper, i somehow completely overlooked creating an extension method! So eventually when it occurred to me, i wrote an extension method which basically makes calls to other methods of the Html helper to provide three fields (whether you use drop down of text inputs is your choice)

```
    public static string DateTime(this HtmlHelper helper, string name)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        string dayName = name + ".Day";
        string monthName = name + ".Month";
        string yearName = name + ".Year";

        builder.Append(helper.TextBox(dayName));
        builder.Append(helper.DropDownList(monthName, typeof (Months)));
        builder.Append(helper.TextBox(yearName));

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

As for the binding after a form post, i simply created a class which implemented `IModelBinder` and set it as default for `DateTime` type on application start. This can then be overridden at a controller action level should a different method of binding be required. This was essentially a simpler version of Scott's binder which i linked to in my question.

Works like a charm at the moment (if a little simplistic), but i'm sure it'll be enough of a foundation for anyone else who is mystified by this problem!